# vBulletin mobile API login_login?

Tags: ios, api, mobile, authentication, vbulletin

I'm new bigginer in vBulletin and I can not find a solution for my problems, I explain,

I would like to create an iOS application that runs with Mobile API vBulletin 5.0, but Now, leave aside iOS.

I would like to create a PHP code that authenticates a user, I already managed to get the result of api_init () so I can use the following vars apiclientid, secret and apiaccesstoken, but I didn't find solution to login a user, I'm calling the method login_login on the api but it return null !

please can someone help on how we can login ? this will be really helpfull,

thank you.

Comment: seems like no one have even small idea concerning this API :/